# Windows Phone c#, how to change button image when in pressed state?

Tags: c#, button, background, windows-phone, blend

For a C# Windows Phone app, how does one have a button that has a .png background, and then the background changes upon a press? To word it a little differently, how can I change the button's background image for the pressed state?

I have a button that I set the background through blend to be a png image. When I go to blend, right click the button and click edit a copy for the template, I click on the pressed state and it goes red showing it is recording. I then go to change the background image but there is a yellow border around it. I cannot change it. If I reset the value so the border goes away I get a warning saying I broke animations. If I ignore it and set it anyway, it sets the "pressed" image as the default image and all states have that image now.

I can't figure out how to make this button just be an image and then display a different image when pressed, and back to the original image when unpressed.

Comment: The second paragraph pretty much explains the generics of what I'm doing that should be working. Randomly one button worked but the other one didn't. I have tried reseting everything with a yellow border around it and it didn't work. I haven't done anything XAML related as I don't get it at all.

Comment: I'm not home at the moment but when I am I will make a video to show what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it programatically to create a "blink" effect when someone presses one of my four arrow images from my on-screen control pad (I re-load the same image, you could load your other image instead):

```
private void imLeft_MouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    _wormDirection = Direction.Left;
    ((Image)sender).Source = null;
}

private void imLeft_MouseLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(25);
    ((Image)sender).Source = imLeftImageSource;
}
```

Comment: This is using the mouse though. I don't believe that is available as an option for windows phone unless touch and taps are considered mouse on the phone. I looked at the properties and I did see mouse but I think it is a mistake cause I couldn't get it to fire with touch.

Comment: This is code for WP7. Touching it with your finger is considered a mouse event.